# Http headers with openfeign

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, openfeign

I need some help) I'm doing some little project with spring boot openfeign client. I have to do 4 http requests. From first GET request I need to get "set-cookie" header out of him get session id. This session ID I need to use in 3 subsequent request (POST, PUT and DELETE). Don't understand clearly how to do it with openfeign. I did it with rest template, but now I need help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoWX1.jpg)
I did FeignClient interface (hopefully right) and now I have to implement these methods in service class

Comment: Don’t post the code as image please

Answer (score 0):

Try use apache HttpClient.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
    <artifactId>feign-httpclient</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**Configure Feign to Use Apache HttpClient**

Create a configuration class for your Feign client that customizes Apache HttpClient to capture cookies. This is just a simple example. In practice, your session should be stored in a better way.

```
@Configuration
public class FeignClientConfig {

    private static String sessionCookie = null;

    @Bean
    public Client feignClient(HttpClient httpClient) {
        return new ApacheHttpClient(httpClient);
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpClient httpClient() {
        return HttpClientBuilder.create()
                .addInterceptorLast((HttpResponseInterceptor) (response, context) -> {
                    // Capture 'Set-Cookie' header from the response
                    if (response.containsHeader("Set-Cookie")) {
                        Header setCookieHeader = response.getFirstHeader("Set-Cookie");
                        sessionCookie = setCookieHeader.getValue();
                    }
                })
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor() {
        return template -> {
            // Apply the captured 'Set-Cookie' value to subsequent requests
            if (sessionCookie != null) {
                template.header("Cookie", sessionCookie);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

**Define the Feign Client**

Define a Feign client that will use the above configuration. This client will make the GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE requests.

```
@FeignClient(name = "apiClient", url = "http://example.com", configuration = FeignClientConfig.class)
public interface ApiClient {
    @GetMapping("/initial")
    String getInitialSession();

    @PostMapping("/subsequent")
    String makePostRequest();

    @PutMapping("/subsequent")
    String makePutRequest();

    @DeleteMapping("/subsequent")
    String makeDeleteRequest();
}
```

**Use the Feign Client**

Finally, use the configured Feign client in your service to perform the HTTP requests.

```
private final ApiClient apiClient;

    @Autowired
    public ApiService(ApiClient apiClient) {
        this.apiClient = apiClient;
    }

    public void executeRequests() {
        // The first request will capture the 'Set-Cookie' header
        String response = apiClient.getInitialSession();

        // Subsequent requests will include the captured cookie
        apiClient.makePostRequest();
        apiClient.makePutRequest();
        apiClient.makeDeleteRequest();
    }
```

FeignClientConfig: This configuration class customizes the Apache HttpClient used by Feign. It intercepts all HTTP responses to capture any Set-Cookie header and saves its value. Then, it uses a RequestInterceptor to apply this captured cookie to all subsequent requests made by the Feign client.

ApiClient: Defines the endpoints for your initial and subsequent requests.

ApiService: Uses the ApiClient to first make an initial request to capture the session cookie, then reuses this cookie for further requests.

**The idea and steps are roughly the example above, and you need to deal with storing and invalidating cookies**